# Is it SEO friendly to step directly from h3 to h5?

Tags: seo, html, tags, heading

Because h5 style of the theme I use is better suited to the design I need. Or do I need to switch styles and keep the tag order.

Answer (score 5):

HTML provides semantic markup to a document. CSS provides information about the presentation. Choosing to use a H5 because of the styling it offers is the wrong reason to use. The only reason why headings, and all tags in HTML, have any styles at all are because web browsers want to be nice and apply default styles to elements. If their chosen default styles do not fit your needs, use CSS to apply your own styles. That's why it's there.

So, use an H4 tag and style it to suit your needs using custom CSS rules.

Comment: However, there is no SEO advantage to being semantically correct.   I don't think there is any advantage at all to being semantically correct.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't matter much.

From the coding side, it's good to be in order and consistent but shouldn't impact SEO h3 vs h5.

These days usability also plays an important role in SEO.

So, have a balance of heading tag and focusing on usability is a good approach.